# gcc optimization diagnostics for lifetime dse

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization

Some GCC optimization options have optional extra diagnostics that tells when a given optimization is applied. For instance `-ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2` will tell about loops which have or not have not been vectorized.

I am wondering if the same flag existed somewhere for `-flifetime-dse`.

I am not too hopeful since my attempts to search the documentation failed. This would be very useful to find bad usage of lifetimes in legacy codebases and correct them, instead of disabling the optimization entirely.

Comment: That may be hard. The compiler inserts in the internal instruction sequence some pseudo-instructions saying that a variable is dead. The flag controls the exact list of positions where those are inserted, but afterwards the dead store elimination is the same optimization whatever the reason things were marked as dead.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out these [1337](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#index-fopt-info-1337) developer options, especially the

```
-fopt-info
```